# ReactJS problem with <p> element visibility

Tags: reactjs, visibility

I have 3 input fields with Name, Address and Year. I pass the length of all the 3 variables as props to this Error component. The errorText should be hidden by default and turn visible if the name is less than 4 letters.

Problem is when I input a name that is less than 4 letters, it changes the errorText variable to the correct "Error in field: name", which I can see by the alert, but the P element still does not change and stays empty.

Also reason why the errorText is not already the one I need by default is, I have more If statements for every alternative instance. For example, if Address and Name are less than 4, then it needs to say "Error in field: address, name".

What could be the issue here? Thanks in advance.

```
const Error = (props) => {
    let errorText = '';
    let isVisible = false;
   
    if (props.nameLength < 4 && props.addressLength >= 4 && props.yearLength >= 4) {
        errorText = "Error in field: name"
        isVisible = true;
        alert("errorText: " + errorText); //This alert is only for testing
    }
    
    return (
    <div>
        <p style={{visibility: isVisible ? "visible" : "hidden"}}>{errorText}</p>
    </div>
    )
}
```

Error is rendered by the following button inside a return:

```
<button type="submit" onClick={() => Error({nameLength, addressLength, yearLength})}>Add</button>
```

Comment: how is `Error` being rendered? Also, are you sure this is the `if` statement that is executed? Can you include the other ones?

Comment: I added the rendering part! @thedude

Comment: It does not look like you are rendering `Error` properly. It should look someting like `<Error nameLength={nameLength} ... >`

Comment: I tried doing it that way but ran into a problem with the errorText being rendered constantly and by every keypress and not by just pressing the Add button @thedude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you should think of components as functions `(state and props) -> elements`
Keeping this in mind, here is a simple implementation of your usecase.

Note that `Error` is always rendered and it reacts to the props values that are passed to it

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Error = ({ nameLength, addressLength, yearLength }) => {
  let errorText = "";

  if (nameLength < 4 && addressLength >= 4 && yearLength >= 4) {
    errorText = "error in field name";
  }

  return errorText ? <div>{errorText}</div> : null;
};

export default function App() {
  const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState("");
  const [addressValue, setAddressValue] = useState("");
  const [yearValue, setYearValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <input
          name="name"
          placeholder="name"
          value={nameValue}
          onChange={(e) => setNameValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
        <input
          name="address"
          placeholder="address"
          value={addressValue}
          onChange={(e) => setAddressValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
        <input
          name="year"
          placeholder="year"
          value={yearValue}
          onChange={(e) => setYearValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <Error
        nameLength={nameValue.length}
        addressLength={addressValue.length}
        yearLength={yearValue.length}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit zealous-babbage-ggp20]

Comment: Ohh, so that's why it was updating constantly. Thanks for the educative comments, I will try to adapt this with the rest of my app!

Answer (score 0):

In react, to affect your DOM we need to use state management. So, every time you're using a variable to change the components/elements it should be provided in state.

try to replace:

```js
let isVisible = false
```

with

```js
const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = React.useState(false);
```

and try to change

```js
isVisible = true
```

inside if with

```js
setIsVisible(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would refactor component in this way, then it should work as you want

```
const Error = (props) => {
    const [error, setError] = useState({errorText: '', isVisible: false})

    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.nameLength < 4 && props.addressLength >= 4 && props.yearLength >= 4) {
        setError({errorText: "Error in field: name", isVisible: true})
      }
    },[])
   
    
    return (
    <div>
        {error?.isVisible && <p>{error?.errorText}</p>}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Working example https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-chihiro-bnlw5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried and got an Invalid hook call error at the "const [error, setError]" part, any ideas?

Comment: Are you importing useState and useEffect ?

Comment: Yes I am @Evren

Comment: It should work here is working example https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-chihiro-bnlw5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will be testing this soon! @Evren

Comment: Could you please choose it as accepted answer if it solved your problem, thanks!

Comment: this will break when the props change (it will not update)

Comment: If props are coming from editable component then it's true, inside useEffect array we can pass [props] and problem is risolved. I am very curious, how did you decide to give downvote without knowing how props are coming to this component? @thedude

Comment: @Evren Your answer contains a non obvious bug (which would cause a lint error in most setups). Maybe you should consider fixing your answer